Centering strings depending on the font size/face height
I'm using this function to center strings inside a window:
(defun center-string (input-string &optional center?)
  "Center each line of the given INPUT-STRING in the current window width.

Acts only when CENTER? is t."
  (let ((window-width (window-width))
    (center? (or center? my-center-content-p)))
    (if center?
      (mapconcat
       (lambda (line)
         (let* ((text (string-trim line))
                (wrapped (with-temp-buffer
                           (insert text)
                           (fill-region (point-min) (point-max))
                           (buffer-string)))
                (lines (split-string wrapped "\n")))
           (mapconcat
            (lambda (line)
              (let ((padding (max (/ (- window-width (length line)) 2) 0)))
                (concat (make-string padding ? ) line)))
            lines
            "\n")))
       (split-string input-string "\n")
       "\n")
      input-string)))

Which works great, all but for one exception.  Centering strings that have a face with an increased size/height (such as modus-themes outlines), for which we have to adjust the padding differently.
How would you adjust for strings that have different "size" properties?
